# Use image_url or image_path in an observer class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, observer-pattern

I want to do some Facebook posting from an observer class, however, I want to reference an image from my server.  In the past I have had some pretty hackie methods of doing this, but now with the new assets stuff, I though I could use image_path or image_url methods.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to call these.  They are not class level methods of ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper so doing

```
ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper.image_url
```

Doesn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, I don't think `image_url` exists. I only see `image_path` [in the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html).

To be able to use that method, you have to include the AssetTagHelper *module*:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
image_path('my_image.png')
```

In Rails 4 include AssetUrlHelper:

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
image_path('my_image.png')
```

Comment: @Matrix with rails 4 you should be able to do this: `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('my_image.png')`

Comment: Actually `image_url` exists in the [Rails 4 API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_url)

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 4 we can use `image_url` with `host` attribute.

As @piotrkaczmarek mentioned above we need to include AssetUrlHelper.

```
include ActionView::Helpers::AssetUrlHelper
image_url('image.jpg', host: 'http://example.com')
```